# Convert array keys to a string in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

Example Array:

```
$array = array([key1] => 
                array([key11] => 
                     array([key111] => 'value111', 
                           [key112] => 'value112', 
                           [key113] => 'value113',
                           [key114] => array(A,B,C,D), 
                          ),
                 ),
           );
```

I need an output as below array:

```
array([key1/key11/key111] => 'value111',
      [key1/key11/key112] => 'value112', 
      [key1/key11/key113] => 'value113',
      [key1/key11/key114] => 'A,B,C,D' );
```

and i have tried using this function,

```
function listArrayRecursive($someArray, &$outputArray, $separator = "/") {
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($someArray), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
    foreach ($iterator as $k => $v) {

        if (!$iterator->hasChildren()) {
            for ($p = array(), $i = 0, $z = $iterator->getDepth(); $i <= $z; $i++) {
                $p[] = $iterator->getSubIterator($i)->key();
            }
            $path = implode($separator, $p);
            $outputArray[] = $path;
        }
    }
}

$outputArray = array();
listArrayRecursive($array, $outputArray);
```

I cant able to find how to achieve this by using the above function for "key1/key11/key114" getting value as i expected. Please help me on this.

Comment: It seems there is a special case in your output that won't make any solution straightforward. You want `key1/key11/key114` to be `A,B,C,D`, when the obvious recursive output would be `key1/key11/key114/0` = `A`, `key1/key11/key114/1` = `B`, `key1/key11/key114/2` = `C`, `key1/key11/key114/3` = `D`. The output you desire will only happen if you have a limited recursion depth or something.

Comment: @Havenard, I need in this way only, if please suggest me another recursive function to do me a job as i expected.

Comment: @Lorenz Meyer What was the complicated you saying in this?

Comment: It was this that made me say complicated : $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($someArray), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

Comment: Using recursive iterators on problems with recursion shouldn't be complicated - in fact the RecursiveIteratorIterator unrolls all the recursiveness into a flat loop - that looks pretty easy to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Input:

```
$array = array(
    'key1' => array(
        'key11' => array(
            'key111' => 'value111', 
            'key112' => 'value112', 
            'key113' => 'value113',
            'key114' => array('A','B','C','D'), 
        ),
        'key12' => array(
            'key121' => 'value121', 
            'key122' => 'value122', 
            'key123' => 'value123',
            'key124' => array('A','B','C','D'), 
        ),
    ),
    'key2' => array(
        'key21' => array(
            'key211' => 'value111', 
            'key212' => 'value112', 
            'key213' => 'value113',
            'key214' => array('A','B','C','D'), 
        ),
    ),
);
```

Script:

```
function remap_keys($input, $max_depth, $separator = '/', /* reserved */ $keychain = array(), /* reserved */ &$output = array())
{
    foreach ($input as $key => $element)
    {
        $element_keychain = array_merge($keychain, (array)$key);
        if (($max_depth > 1) && is_array($element))
            remap_keys($element, $max_depth -1, $separator, $element_keychain, $output);
        else
            $output[implode($separator, $element_keychain)] = implode(',', (array)$element);
    }
    return $output;
}


$array = remap_keys($array, 3);

print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [key1/key11/key111] => value111
    [key1/key11/key112] => value112
    [key1/key11/key113] => value113
    [key1/key11/key114] => A,B,C,D
    [key1/key12/key121] => value121
    [key1/key12/key122] => value122
    [key1/key12/key123] => value123
    [key1/key12/key124] => A,B,C,D
    [key2/key21/key211] => value111
    [key2/key21/key212] => value112
    [key2/key21/key213] => value113
    [key2/key21/key214] => A,B,C,D
)
```

http://ideone.com/pqH45h

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array('key1' => 
                array('key11' => 
                     array('key111' => 'value111', 
                           'key112' => 'value112', 
                           'key113' => 'value113',
                           'key114' => array(A,B,C,D), 
                          ),
                 ),
           );
function implode_arr_keys($array, $output_arr = array(), $cur_key = FALSE) {
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if(is_array($value)) {
            return implode_arr_keys($value, $output_arr, ($cur_key == FALSE ? $key : $cur_key.'/'.$key));
        } else {
            if(!is_numeric($key))
                $output_arr[$cur_key.'/'.$key] = $value;
            else
                $output_arr[$cur_key] = $array;
        }
    }
    return $output_arr;
}
print_r($array);
print_r(implode_arr_keys($array));
```

Comment: This works only if the first layers have only one element each.